# Django: Loop Queryset inside Queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset

So I have queryset1 that filters ModelA by 2 parameters:

```
queryset1 = ModelA.objects.all().filter(par1="X",par2="Y")
```

Then I have another queryset2 that I would like to filter ModelB by grabbing the elements that have already been filtered by queryset1, and also that follow another parameter:

```
queryset2 = ModelB.objects.all().filter(par3="X" for i in queryset,par4="Z")
```

My question is:
Is there a way to perform a queryset on a queryset that you have already made? 
In the end I would like to pull the objects from ModelA and ModelB that follow par1 par2 par3. How would I do this?

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to do, can you show us your model? What's the relationship between `ModelA` and `ModelB`? What are you trying to do with `for i in queryset`?

Comment: ModelA and ModelB have some of the same objects, but some different objects. I want to grab the objects that are the same in both models, then do a filter on those objects.

Comment: please post examples of models so it is a little more clear

Comment: Oh that's what you are doing? No, in django you can't filter on 2 models. Queryset needs to be objects from one model only.

Comment: Post your model code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's quite possible to achieve without a for loop. The disadvantage of using a for loop is that you are actually executing two queries and retrieving the results for the first one. If that happens to produce a large number of rows you are burning up resources and slowing down the response time.

```
queryset2 = ModelB.objects.all().filter(par3__in=queryset,par4="Z")
```

This would result in a subquery as explained at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/

> You can also use a queryset to dynamically evaluate the list of values
>   instead of providing a list of literal values:

```
SELECT * FROM app_modelb where par3 IN (SELECT ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is:

1. When `par3` is a `relation` of the same type of the `queryset1`:

   ```
   queryset2 = ModelB.objects.all().filter(par3__in=queryset1, par4="Z")
   ```
2. Use the `values_list('some_field', flat=True)` notation, when `part3` is not a `relation`

   ```
   queryset2 = ModelB.objects.all().filter(par3__in=queryset1.values_list('X', flat=True), par4="Z")
   ```